# Angular 2.0 lifecycle and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2.0 component and I wanted to add lifecycle events to it (Angular 2.0 Alfa 35).

I was looking at this [post](http://learnangular2.com/lifecycle/) as a reference, but Typescript gave me errors for using the

`import {Component, View, EventEmitter, onInit} from 'angular2/angular2';`

(error on `onInit`). A quick look at Angular2 code revealed that the export uses `OnInit` (with capital `O`). I changed the import code but the lifecycle event itself is still `onInit`. This is my component (I cannot make onInit event happen):

```
import {Component, View, EventEmitter, OnInit} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'theme-preview-panel-component',
  properties: ['fontSize'],
  lifecycle: [onInit]
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '../components/theme-preview-panel-component/theme-preview-panel-component.tpl.html',
})
export class ThemePreviewPanelComponent {
  fontSize: string;
  constructor() {
  }

  onInit() {
    //This code is not being called
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

As @Eric Martinez mentioned below, the solution is:

```
import {Component, View, EventEmitter, LifecycleEvent} from 'angular2/angular2';

    @Component({
      selector: 'theme-preview-panel-component',
      properties: ['fontSize'],
      lifecycle: [LifecycleEvent.onInit]
    })
    @View({
        templateUrl: '../components/theme-preview-panel-component/theme-preview-panel-component.tpl.html',
    })
    export class ThemePreviewPanelComponent {
      fontSize: string;
      constructor() {
      }

      onInit() {
        //Now this code is being called
      }
    }
```

Comment: Import `LifecycleEvent.onInit` and specify it the same way in your `lifecycle` property.

Comment: Not sure I am following. Tried this: `import {Component, View, EventEmitter, LifecycleEvent.onInit} from 'angular2/angular2';
` and got a TS error : `error TS1005: ',' expected.` Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: So sorry, I made a mistake. You should import `LifecycleEvent` and then use it like `LifecycleEvent.onInit` in your `lifecycle` property. My bad.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem